# extract Element from div with jSoup returns null

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract a string from a web page: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitmango.rolltheballunrollme. The string I want is in: `<div class="id-app-title" tabindex="0">Roll the Ball™ - slide puzzle</div>`.

I've looked at https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax and I'm pretty sure I'm following the instructions, but I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gaspacho.Gaspacho.getAppTitle(Gaspacho.java:109)
at gaspacho.Gaspacho.alphabetty(Gaspacho.java:94)
at gaspacho.Gaspacho.main(Gaspacho.java:27)
/home/david/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

This is the method I'm using:

```
public void getAppTitle(String url){
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Element appTitleElement = document.select("div.id-app-title" ).first();

        String title = appTitleElement.toString();

        System.out.println(title);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help you can give would be appreciated

Comment: I guess this is returning null: `document.select("div.id-app-title")` and `first()` cannot be called, so, `NullPointerException`. Can you test that this is returning something or not?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, selector is correct, value is found and printed.

Comment: System.out.println(title); prints 'null'

Comment: I'm getrting the correct output. Try to set your `userAgent` string - maybe you are getting different responses for the browser and your app.